# How to Compress JSON data in angular 4 app using gzip compression & send it to server using Http post?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, angular, typescript

I am using pako library for compression:

```
 var binaryString = pako.gzip(data);
```

At server side (.net core) i am using middleware to decomopress the zipped string.

```
 try
 {
     context.Request.Body = new GZipStream(context.Request.Body, CompressionMode.Decompress);
 }
```

But i am getting error as **the archive entry was compressed using an unsupported compression method**

Comment: Hi .. are you using Asp.NET WEBPI 2?

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi yes, thats why i am using middle-ware instead of Handlers.

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi sorry its .net core 2.0

Comment: having basically the same issue in asp.net core 2 @SagarK any luck?

Answer (score 0):

```
 compress(objectYouWantToCompress: any) {
 var data = JSON.stringify(objectYouWantToCompress);
 var binaryString = this.pako.gzip(data);
 return btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(binaryString)));
}
```

this can decompress on .net to your required object

on dotnet side:

```
public string Unzip(string str)
{
     byte[] bytes=Convert.FromBase64String(str);
     using (var msi = new MemoryStream(bytes))
     using (var mso = new MemoryStream())
     {
         using (var gs = new GZipStream(msi, CompressionMode.Decompress))
           {
                    CopyTo(gs, mso);
           }

                return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mso.ToArray());
       }
 }
```